# Simple way to monitor Camel's localhost broker

Tags: apache-camel

as stated, is there a simple way to monitor Camel's vm incoming messages to the embedded broker ?

```
<bean id="jms" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
        <property name="brokerURL" value="vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false" />
</bean>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't quite clear on what you would like to monitor.

-You could log what you send to the broker and read from it.
-You could connect to jmx to view a bunch of processing information.
-If you are on the FUSE platform there is a management console that exposes the jmx endpoints to a web url.
-You could also setup JBoss operations network to poll all of your jmx info and do trending on the data.

If I didn't cover the use case you had in mind please update your question with some details and ping me in a comment so I can get back to you.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for not being so clear however as far as I understand from the docs and your reply the best choice would be to connect to JMX (I am not allowed change the route by adding log components)